# can we have Tag Icons

Tags: feature-request

On Stack Overflow the facebook, Android, and adobe [tags have icons on](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=2&tab=popular), could we allow Icons for tags such as iTunes, App Store, Bluetooth, Mail.app, etc?

Comment: I'm curious what the use case for these icons would be? I personally don't like them at all, but perhaps I'm not seeing the benefit?

Comment: just an aesthetic. It does help in some instances such as the Adobe programs all having the Adobe icon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tag icons are sponsored. Companies purchase the right to put their icon on a tag for a period of time. As far as I am aware this is currently only done on StackOverflow, and not on the rest of the network.

Comment: Thanks, I can't see apple doing that anytime, shame, never mind.

Comment: How do you know this? Where did you get to know this?

Comment: @Matt Apart from being involved with SE since it first started, from the official FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean

Comment: Very nice. Thanks!